# mosquitto_sub with TLS enabled

Tags: mqtt, tls1.2, mosquitto

I am new to MQTT and I have a frustrating problem.

I have been using MQTT.fx to subscribe to a topic; I have set the:

- Broker Address
- Port
- Client ID
- Enable SSL/TLS 
  [image: link to image]
- Topic

This works well, however I would like to use mosquitto_sub.
I am attempting to subscribe to the same topic in the following way:

```
mosquitto_sub -h  host -p 8883 -t topic -i client id
```

This is not working for me. I am using it on a Ubuntu VM.
My powers of observation tell me that I should enable TLS, however I'm not quite sure how to do that, I have stuffed around with certificates and enabling TLS in may ways but have not got the right combo. I know it is required as if I uncheck the SSL/TLS box in MQTT.fx I am unable to connect.

I would really like to replicate what I have in MQTT.fx with mosquitto.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In the mosquitto_sub command, use the --capath argument to point to /etc/ssl/certs. It needs a pointer to the trusted certificates.

Answer (score 5):

To enable SSL with mosquitto_sub you need to specify a CA certificate.

This can be done in 1 of 2 ways.

1. `--cafile /path/to/a/file` where the file contains the required trusted CA certificate (either on it's own or part of a concatenated set)
2. `--capath /path/to/directory` where the directory contains a collection of files ending in .crt which contain the CA certificates to be trusted. The ca certs should also be indexed with the [c_rehash](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/apps/c_rehash.html) function.

Both these options are mentioned in the mosquito_sub [man page](https://mosquitto.org/man/mosquitto_sub-1.html) as ways to enabled SSL

e.g.

```
mosquitto_sub -h host -p 8883 --cafile ca.crt -t topic -i client id
```

Answer (score 1):

i am aware of a 3rd way (short cut) which is using the flag `--tls-use-os-certs`

also as a side note, mosquitto_sub/pub also sends SNI within the tls connection request, which is great news if you are using SNI based routing on the broker side.

don't know if the MQTT standard actually prescribes this, but at least mosquitto client's implementation does support it