# Where do I find the ca certificates for mosquitto_sub and pub?

Tags: ssl, mosquitto

In this article [mosquitto_sub with TLS enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43826046/mosquitto-sub-with-tls-enabled) I understand that you need to provide a capath or cafile option to mosquitto_sub (and pub) but I am having trouble figuring out where those files/paths come from.

Back in October I was able to run `mosquitto_sub -h mymosquitto.com -p 8883 -v -t 'jim/#' -u <u> -P <pw> --capath ssl/certs` from my desktop computer (running Mint 19).  That no longer works.  I did an apt install ca-certificates and found the .crt files in `/usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/` but when I used that path, it still gave me: Error: A TLS error occurred.

This is a Ubuntu 18.04 server running Let'sencrypt.  I tried to point the `--cafile` to the chain.pem file which came from:

```
allow_anonymous false
password_file /etc/mosquitto/pwfile

listener 1883 

listener 8883
certfile /etc/letsencrypt/live/mymosquitto.com/cert.pem
cafile /etc/letsencrypt/live/mymosquitto.com/chain.pem
keyfile /etc/letsencrypt/live/mymosquitto.com/privkey.pem
```

But that didn't work either.  Can someone please help me understand what I should be doing?

Answer (score 1):

From the `mosquitto_sub` man page:

> **--capath**
>
> Define the path to a directory containing PEM encoded CA certificates that are trusted. Used to enable SSL communication.
>
> For --capath to work correctly, the certificate files must have ".crt" as the file ending and you must run "openssl rehash [path to
> capath]" each time you add/remove a certificate.

If you want to use a directory of certs you will have to make sure the `openssl rehash` command mentioned has been run on that directory.

If you want use a file from the letsencrypt `--cafile` with the `fullchain.pem` file

Answer (score 0):

I have rethought my situation.  Since my certs get regenerated every 3 months or so I'm going to have to redo my apps using the new files so I decided to just go back to rolling my own.  I did that using this site: http://www.steves-internet-guide.com/mosquitto-tls/ and I'm back to where I was in October.Thanks to hardillb for the advise.

Jim.